# Why would Google account show hundreds of YouTube purchases?

Tags: google-account, google, youtube

Google allows deleting Google products within a Google account.

A friend's Google account shows that it has a YouTube profile within his account.

My friend does not use YouTube, so he went into the Google account manager to delete the YouTube profile.  When trying to delete his YouTube profile, Google warned that doing so will **delete his 1525 YouTube purchases!**

My friend states that he has never purchased anything on YouTube, nor has he ever provided Google with a payment method.  Before deleting his YouTube account, how can he see these hundreds of purchases that Google has claimed he made on YouTube?

### *Update*

Our always helpful Dan Brown recommended reading:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2850369

Based on the info in that article, I had my friend look at his order history in the Android Play Store.  It showed hundreds (perhaps 1525?!) of orders for items that had no cost: free music tracks, videos, digital magazines, and digital books.

All of the items are from the Play Store; **none of the items appear to have anything to do with YouTube!**

So either this means:

1. He has an additional 1525 purchases in YouTube.  But how does he view those?

or

2. For some reason Google is claiming that deleting a YouTube profile will result in the loss of 1525 free Play Store items.  Why would YouTube have anything to do with Play Store orders?

Comment: 1525? What the? Anyway, I suggest He looks on the play stores settings, and see what these purchases are.

Comment: @DanBrown LOL.  I know... bizarre, right?  I'm not sure if Play Store settings is the right place, since the purchases are for YouTube.  Either way, `play.google.com/settings` only shows *Email and Notification Preferences* and *Devices*.  What's the URL or sequence to get the correct page?

Comment: Try this https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2850369%3Fhl%3Den&ved=0ahUKEwic9qXbvqnQAhWFIcAKHWoACQkQFggcMAE&usg=AFQjCNH7Xu_oNmi53ckCw10eZ4qyHSJ8dQ&sig2=zjc7Po7Eh65L0gtlEAvPZg

Comment: For those interested, a direct url to that page is https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2850369

Comment: @DanBrown Thanks Dan.  Did you write that article (it was written by someone named *Dan*)?  Based on that link, I'll update the question with further details.

Comment: It could be point one. COULD. I went to the delete page, and it said 3 items - I have 3 movies, two paid. I have dozens of books and music tracks though.....

Comment: @DanBrown That's good info, thanks.  Did you purchase those movies on YouTube or from the Google Play Store?

Comment: Purchased via Google play. Still unsure how Google works sometimes :)

Comment: @DanBrown LOL. So you bought 3 movies (1 free, and 2 paid) from the Google Play Store, but when you try to delete your **YouTube** profile, Google tells you that you will lose your Google Play Store content?  Is that correct?  If so, that matches what my friend is experiencing.

Comment: Exactly. I would then go and experiment, but there's no free movies available to try on a alternate account.